# execute macros in multiple excel files

Tags: vba, excel

my problem is to set up a macro for excel which has to make the same actions repeatedly evolving another excel files and their macros, i show:

i have a base .xlsm file with some macros which end creating a new excel file with my useful data.
I have copied the base file to a bunch of directories where it has the proper behaviour.

**Can I do some kind of scan with Dir() and say:
- open the excel.
- run the macros,
?**

May be I have some problems with some code because of ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheets usage **here is a sample**

> this is used to give a new xlsm that I create as result it's file
>   name:

```
    nombre = Range("B1")
    camino = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Path = camino + "\" + nombre + ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(Path)
```

thank you in advance,

**Second update**,

the previous macro, which does is to import and distribute a lot of information from a lot of text files in the same directory to the same sheet, then it saves the file with a proper name (what I showed you). When I use it individually, the new file that has been created has within the same macros than the original one and I continue executing more macros from there. I hope this helps ^^

This is an important script that deletes information that I don't need (and I don't want to delete things that I need),

```
Sub abDOS_borrar_no_interesa() 'Borro lo que sea -1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
f = 5

Do While f < 3787
c_pasadas = 1
c = 5
Do While c_pasadas < colum + 1
leo = Cells(f, c)
If leo = "-1" Or leo = "0" Then
Cells(f, c - 2).ClearContents 'si no quieres que se borre borra esta linea o comentala
Cells(f, c - 1).ClearContents 'si no quieres que se borre borra esta linea o comentala
Cells(f, c).ClearContents 'si no quieres que se borre borra esta linea o comentala

'Si quieres que en vez de borrar los datos los ponga en gris
'Cells(f, c - 2).Font.Color = -16711681
'Cells(f, c - 1).Font.Color = -16711681
'Cells(f, c).Font.Color = -16711681


End If
c = c + 3
c_pasadas = c_pasadas + 1
Loop
f = f + 1
Loop

Cells(2, 1) = Mid(Range("A1"), 5, 4)
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**More update:**
I found a sample code:

```
    Sub ejecucion_Total()
    Dim xl As Object
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Activate
    xl.Workbooks.Open (ActiveCell)
    xl.Run "procesar"
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing 
    End Sub
```

and as I expected it gives to me an error while saving the file that has to be created.

Comment: There's not much detail here, but you can use `Dir()` to locate the files, and `Application.Run` to run macros in them once you've got them open.  Whether your macros will run OK depends on how you wrote them...  It would help if you could post specific examples of code you think might cause problems.

Comment: Updated with some sample, ask for more if it isn't enough

Comment: That looks like the code you used to create the files: what about the code within the files? Isn't that what you want to run? I'm guessing it will be fine, but without a full review it's imposssible to be certain.

Comment: buf i'll add it, but it's a bunch a bit horrible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4546471/62576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

My solution uses an iterative variation of the ***More update code*** that I posted.
It opens and runs the code in the other excels and then closes them. (I had to change some relative uses like Activesheet etc,).

I'll post it here later.